# Can I offer user to switch current WiFi connection programmatically?

Tags: android, wifi

I'm trying to switch between 2 WiFi networks, but not behind the scene. I saw such dialog in iOS it calls system dialog.
Not sure if this is possible in Android.

Offering user to switch network also means no permission is asked.

Update:
For moment the only way is to open wifi settings screen, but this doesn't give user an idea witch network to select:

```java
startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS), 0);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this Action_wifi_setting is not 100% guaranteed to work.

Better try with ACTION_PICK_WIFI_NETWORK. This will show system screen with WiFi connections.